# Command block problem detecting armour

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I'm trying to detect when I'm wearing a unbreakable black leather boots with a lore, a name, and enchants. Here's the code:

```
/testfor @p {Inventory:[{Slot:100b,id:"minecraft:leather_boots",tag:{Unbreakable:1,display:{Name:"shadow sandals",Lore:[_____],color:0},ench:[{id:0,lvl:31073},{id:7,lvl:31073},{id:4,lvl:31073},{id:3,lvl:31073}]}}]}}}
```

But it says that it has unbalanced curly brackets, can someone help me fix this and give me the corrected command?

PS: The testfor is so when I wear the boots it will give me a potion effect.

Comment: @bearb001 Your edit to this question was not helpful, as the interface for specifying commands in minecraft only allows a single line of input. Additionally, it had the effect of invalidating my duplicate flag.

Comment: @pppery As I said in an earlier comment, I didn't know that editing the question would have that effect. I'm sorry. The edit did improve readability and it does help with troubleshooting, because it's much easier to see what is going on in the command and what is causing certain syntax errors. You can also still copy and paste it into a command block.

Comment: @bearb001 Yes, it does improve readability of the question, but in the process of doing so, it mangles the input into the command block. guest did not type line breaks into a command block in minecraft, as doing so is impossible. Your "improvement to readability" came at the expense of accuracy.

Comment: @pppery I don't see how the accuracy is reduced, the line breaks won't transfer over to the command block when copying and pasting, because, as you said, that's not possible. The only difference would be some extra spaces, which don't affect the command. Feel free to roll back the edit (or suggest to roll it back?) if you feel like that's the right thing to do.

Comment: @bearb001 [done](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/273448)

Comment: @pppery This edit improves readability. It should be kept because JSON formatting is much cleaner in that form. If the other version is really desired for some people, put both, the condensed at the bottom of the expanded. One extra line never hurt anyone.

Comment: @Nik3141 I don't dispute that linebreaks and whitespace improve the readability of NBT tags (which aren't actually JSON), but that's simply not relevant. In the question I tried to dupe this to, the first part of the answer is "Use a tool to add whitespace, so you can more easily find the error". Thus, by adding whitespace, you're not only changing the question so the command listed is different from what was actually run in the command block, but your making steps toward solving it, which isn't appropriate for an edit. And I view having duplicate information in the question as a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

You've got two extra curly brackets at the end. After the last square bracket closed `Inventory`, you only need 1 more curly bracket to end the tag:

```
/testfor @p {Inventory:[{Slot:100b,id:"minecraft:leather_boots",tag:{Unbreakable:1,display:{Name:"shadow sandals",Lore:[_____],color:0},ench:[{id:0,lvl:31073},{id:7,lvl:31073},{id:4,lvl:31073},{id:3,lvl:31073}]}}]}
```

The command should now work, if you're giving the boots with something like:

```
/give @p leather_boots 1 0 {Unbreakable:1,display:{Name:"shadow sandals",Lore:[_____],color:0},ench:[{id:0,lvl:31073},{id:7,lvl:31073},{id:4,lvl:31073},{id:3,lvl:31073}]}
```

Keep in mind however that `id` and `lvl` are shorts by default, and `Unbreakable` is a byte by default. This means that, if you've added the tags by another means, you should specify these types in your testfor command:

```
/testfor @p {Inventory:[{Slot:100b,id:"minecraft:leather_boots",tag:{Unbreakable:1b,display:{Name:"shadow sandals",Lore:[_____],color:0},ench:[{id:0s,lvl:31073s},{id:7s,lvl:31073s},{id:4s,lvl:31073s},{id:3s,lvl:31073s}]}}]}
```

Comment: thx a lot XD really helped me

Comment: @guest No problem, press the tick to the left of the answer to accept it if it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

You have too many curly braces ( } ). Try:

```
/testfor @p {Inventory:[{Slot:100b,id:"minecraft:leather_boots",tag:{Unbreakable:1,display:{Name:"shadow sandals",Lore:[_____],color:0},ench:[{id:0,lvl:31073},{id:7,lvl:31073},{id:4,lvl:31073},{id:3,lvl:31073}]}}]}
```

Comment: thx, really helped

Comment: Here's a tip: Use the "`" character to separate your command from everything else (surround command in them). It makes your answer a lot more readable!

Comment: @DanielG That character is primarily for inline code, while a lengthy command on its own line would use a code block (4 spaces).